# When i click register button Form Data not stored in database

Tags: php, cakephp

I am developing the simple register form in cakephp,but the problem is form data not stored in database.
here the code.

**Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
username VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL ,
password VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL ,
email VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
first_name VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL ,
last_name VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL
)
```

**user.php(model class)**

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel
{
var $name='User';
}
?>
```

**register.ctp(view class):**

```
<h3>Registration Form><h3>
<form action="../registers/register" method="POST" name="form">
Username:<input type="text" name="username">
password:<input type="password" name="password">
email:<input type="text" name="email">
FirstName:<input type="text" name="firstname">
LastName:<input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

**RegistersController:(controller class)**

```
<?php


class RegistersController extends AppController
{

    function register(){
        if (!empty($this->params['form']))
        {
            if($this->User->save($this->params['form']))
            {
                $this->flash('Registration Successful','/users/register');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->flash('Not succeeded','/users/register');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should get data in `$this->request->data` and not in `$this->params['form']`.

Comment: IF i use this $this->request->data it will display the error message like this   Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object
File: D:\xampp\htdocs\project\UserRegisterForm\app\Controller\RegistersController.php
Line: 23

Comment: Yes, that because you're not following cake convention as @arillia answered below.

Comment: i am read the documentation..but am unable to follow the conventions.please tel me some links for easy understandng the cakephp

Comment: Your CakePHP version?

Comment: can you post the value of $this->params['form'] please?

Comment: Don't post anything, read documentation again and again as long as it takes. What you are doing here is completely wrong. You created controller which is basically action in users controller. You are not yet ready to take on frameworks I guess and read even more then I said.

Comment: @ Fazal Rasel m iam using cakephp 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your $this->params['form'] array should me be in form like:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [username] => test
            [password] => test
            [email] => test
            [first_name] => test
            [last_name] => test
        )

)
```

so please check that

also yopu can debug like:

```
<?php


class RegistersController extends AppController
{
    public $uses = array('User');

    function register(){
        if (!empty($this->params['form']))
        {
            if($this->User->save($this->params['form']))
            {
                $this->flash('Registration Successful','/users/register');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->flash('Not succeeded','/users/register');
            }
            $log=$this->User->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
            echo "<pre>";print_r($log);exit;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and you are getting this error

```
Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object File: D:\xampp\htdocs\project\UserRegisterForm\app\Controller\RegistersController.php
```

because you havent loaded User model

Comment: please write the code completly.If i am doning same work also not save the data in database

Answer (score 1):

as we said in the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813178/error-the-view-for-appcontrollerindex-was-not-found) question you are not using cakephp conventions.

In facts now you are trying to dave a `User` from a `RegistersController`. But you don't have any User data in your request because the data comes from a `Register` form

Turn your `RegistersController` to a `UsersController` (and also move the register.ctp file from Registers to Users folder).

But you are making other mistakes, for example you are not using FormHelper to create your form and so the data you are sending to your controller is not as cake expects to be.

And there are other errors in your controller too.

So first of all read again the manual!

PS: maybe this should be a comment and not an answer but it's too long and SO doesn't let me post it as a comment.

Comment: I think he didn't read your previous answer at all, otherwise this mistake would have been avoided...